# How to access method inside object of object through method refrence

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are two classes A & B. For example given below:

```
class A{
    B b;
    B getB(){ return b; }
}

class B{
    String x = "Test";
    String getX(){
       return x;
    }
}
```

I have object of A in `.map(method_refrence_here_for_getX)` and I want to call getX so there is any way to do it?

Although i can do like below:

```
.map(A::getB)
.map(B::getX)

or

.map( a -> a.getB().getX())
```

But I want to do something like `.map(A::B::getX)` I know it's absolutely wrong but I want something like this so anyone can help?

Comment: you can't and you already have listed the only possible options

Comment: @Eugene ooops I missed that.

Comment: @Eugene @Holger Could this not be achieved using a method within class `A` implemented as `String returnXFromA(){ return getB().getX();}` and then referencing it as `A::returnXFromA`? Or maybe I am missing things worse in this kind of approach.

Comment: @nullpointer of course, but that does not really change the problem on chaining method references

Comment: @nullpointer of course, you can create a method of the form `static String someName(A a) { return a.getB().getX(); }` and use a method reference like `MyType::someName`, but that’s *exactly* what you get when using the much simpler lambda expression `a -> a.getB().getX()`. The only difference is that the method will be marked as “Synthetic” on the bytecode level in the lambda expression case.

Answer (score 1):

You simply **can't**. There is no syntax for that *and* it's called a *method reference* (**method**) and you potentially show a field reference, which is not supported and looks weird to begin with IMO.

There is a difference between the two (`map(A::getB).map(B::getX)` and `map(a -> a.getB().getX())`) is that you will save an additional method internally, but this is one tiny optimization and you should really look into what is more readable in your opinion.

Comment: Weird workaround: `.map(((Function<A, B>) A::getB).andThen(B::getX))`, shouldn't be used though

Comment: @Lino even though it adds one more option to the possible ones (and I totally missed it)